# IOExceptions with H2 database

Tags: playframework, h2

Recentently I get IOExceptions from an Play app that uses the H2 database. Something like this:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Block not found in id [1, -68, 2, 2] [1.4.187/50]
  at org.h2.mvstore.StreamStore$Stream.read(StreamStore.java:466) ~[com.h2database.h2-1.4.187.jar:1.4.187]
  at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
  at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
  at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
  at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
  at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
  at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:212) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
  at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:286) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
  at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.DataHelper.extractString(DataHelper.java:88) ~[org.hibernate.hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
```

It might be the issue they are talking about in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/myX5RH6cV-8 or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/Gv5Nu2subzM. Here someone writes '1.4.186, 1.4.187 and 1.4.188 are the vulnerable versions.'. In my Play version (2.4.3) the H2 version 1.4.187 is used.

It seems to happen sporadically and so far I could not find any reason for when it happened.

I wonder why there is not much more to find in the Internet about this issue. An unstable database seems to be quite important. I just set the version to the latest 1.4.191 and will closely monitor it. Does anyone have had similar experiences with H2 and Play?

Comment: Hey! I'm having the same problem. Apparently in that discussion they say the issue was fixed, but I'm using build 1.4.191 and I see the problem over and over. This started after a number of changes were made related to closing database connections, so I'm sure it is related. I will keep investigating and reading around and see if I figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the original question. Yes, I recently had that experience when I was using build .187.

I had the following exception:

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.io.IOException: Block not found in id [1, -109, 3, 1] [1.4.187/50]"; "lob: null table: -3 id: 7" [90031-187]

... with a similar stacktrace as yours.

Once I moved to build .192 the problem went away completely. The problem is listed as fixed in version 1.4.189 Beta (2015-09-13) based on the change logs:

http://www.h2database.com/html/changelog.html

So, we move up to .192 and close our fingers that something like this doesn't happen again !!!

Comment: Thanks Jose! I'll try 192. So far I haven't had time to work on it again. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Update: So far I've never had this error again. So 192 seems to work. I'm still unhappy that this happens with H2 at all. I don't want to use an unreliable database. :(

Comment: I had this problem with 192 now. And switching to 193 at least doesn't fix it for the now broken database. :-(